# Insert in Database with PHP variable

Tags: php, variables, insert, mysqli

I've an issue with my code.
I want to insert PHP variables ($variable) in my database.

But I've this error :

```
 Erreur SQL !
INSERT INTO info(nom, prenom, entreprise, email, objet, message) VALUES(test,toto,overflow,toto@hotmail.fr,Autre,TEST)
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '@hotmail.fr,Autre,TEST)' at line 1
```

My code :

```
<?php 
// Connection to MySQL 
$db = mysqli_connect('****', '***', '','****') or die("Erreur de connexion au serveur !!!"); 

// Create request
$sql = "INSERT INTO info(nom, prenom, entreprise, email, objet, message) VALUES($nom,$prenom,$entreprise,$email,$objet,$message)";

// Send request to DB
$req = mysqli_query($db,$sql) or die('Erreur SQL !<br>'.$sql.'<br>'.mysqli_error($db));  

// Close connection
$deconnexion = mysqli_close(mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '','contact'));
?>
```

I want to use mysqli to do this insert.

What is wrong in my INSERT INTO ?

Comment: String values need to be quoted.... but you're using MySQLi so why not move into the 21st century and start using prepared statements/bind variables

Comment: @MarkBaker Thx Mark :)  Ok, so I've to do this : $sql = "INSERT INTO info(nom, prenom, entreprise, email, objet, message) VALUES('$nom','$prenom','$entreprise','$email','$objet','$message')";

Comment: If you were using bind variables, you wouldn't need to remember to quote your strings, or to escape your inserted variables

Comment: How to do this ? It's better than my solution ?

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.prepare.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO info (nom, prenom, entreprise, email, objet, message) VALUES ('$nom','$prenom','$entreprise','$email','$objet','$message')";
```

String values need to be quoted.

A better and alternative way to do this below.

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO info (nom, prenom, entreprise, email, objet, message) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
$sql->bindParam('ssssss', $nom, $prenom, $entreprise, $email, $objet, $message);
$sql->execute();
```

[bindParam](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) from php manual.

Comment: I've issue with apostrophe variable... How to escape this ?

Comment: Can you write that issue in another question?

Comment: Also prepared statements take care of quotes. http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php

Comment: +1 for the bind params example

Comment: I understand but it's the same code...
I try with mysqli_real_escape_string(), but that doesn't works..

Comment: @gloops100 Please post a question with values giving you the problem.

Comment: @chanchal118 Ok no problem

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
<?php 
// Connection to MySQL 
$db = mysqli_connect('****', '***', '','****') or die("Erreur de connexion au serveur !!!"); 

// Create request
$sql = "INSERT INTO info(nom, prenom, entreprise, email, objet, message) VALUES('$nom','$prenom','$entreprise','$email','$objet','$message')";

// Send request to DB
$req = mysqli_query($db,$sql) or die('Erreur SQL !<br>'.$sql.'<br>'.mysqli_error($db));  

// Close connection
$deconnexion = mysqli_close(mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '','contact'));
?>
```